# Insert select from ignoring function errors

Tags: mysql, insert

I'm changing database structure of a very large existing database using some performance related improvements. Once created the new architecture, I'm moving data from old structure to the new one. To achieve this I'm running this query:

```
insert ignore into newschema.delivery
SELECT UUID_TO_BIN(substring(id, 35)), start_at, assigned_at, accepted_at, prepared_at,
  delivered_at, no_carrier_at, failed_at, cancelled_at, currency, amount, retail_amount, customer,
  UUID_TO_BIN(substring(shift, 32)), street1, street2, notes, latitude, longitude, customer_rating, carrier_rating, 
  canceller, cancellation_reason, last_updated, rating_customer_problem, personal_discount, item_discount, 
  cancellation_reason_key, fee_amount, fee_debt_amount, rating_customer_description
FROM oldschema.delivery as i1
on duplicate key update
  start_at=i1.start_at, assigned_at=i1.assigned_at, accepted_at=i1.accepted_at, prepared_at=i1.prepared_at, 
  delivered_at=i1.delivered_at, no_carrier_at=i1.no_carrier_at, failed_at=i1.failed_at, cancelled_at=i1.cancelled_at, 
  currency=i1.currency, amount=i1.amount, retail_amount=i1.retail_amount, customer=i1.customer, 
  shift=UUID_TO_BIN(substring(i1.shift, 32)), street1=i1.street1, street2=i1.street2, notes=i1.notes, 
  latitude=i1.latitude, longitude=i1.longitude, customer_rating=i1.customer_rating, carrier_rating=i1.carrier_rating, 
  canceller=i1.canceller, cancellation_reason=i1.cancellation_reason, last_updated=i1.last_updated, 
  rating_customer_problem=i1.rating_customer_problem, personal_discount=i1.personal_discount, 
  item_discount=i1.item_discount, cancellation_reason_key=i1.cancellation_reason_key, fee_amount=i1.fee_amount, 
  fee_debt_amount=i1.fee_debt_amount, rating_customer_description=i1.rating_customer_description;
```

In current schema uuids are stored as char, in new schema uuids are stored as binary; performance is greatly improved but there are some (despreciable) rows with bad formatted uuid that break query execution at all.

How can i run this query ignoring function errors (if it's possible)?

thanks in advance,

Comment: Huh?  Why are you passing substrings to `UUID_TO_BIN`?

Comment: What database technology are you working with?

Comment: current id is composed by a prefix and a unique identifier in uuid format, substring removes this prefix.

Comment: We use MySQL as database server

Answer (score 0):

That is not the normal way to use IODKU.

Instead of

```
... UPDATE
foo = i1.stuff ...
```

do

```
... UPDATE
foo = VALUES(foo), ...
```

What is the Unique key in the table?

Comment: `id` is the unique key in the table